# Check if matching child records exist before saving parent records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

We basically have a set of child records in which we will use to create a new parent/child record(s) but need to first verify that a parent record doesn't already exist containing the same child records. Here are the details:

We have 3 tables, one is basically a linking table between the parent and children records.

Table A (parent table)

```
Id
Name
Desc
```

Table B (linking table between tables A and C)

```
Id
TableAId
TableCId
```

Table C (child table)

```
Id
StartPosition
EndPosition
Percentage
```

So with that structure, here is an example of a complete record, the parent table it one-to-many relation with child table:

Table A

```
(1, 'Sample', 'N/A')
```

Table B

```
(1, 1, 1)
(2, 1, 2)
(3, 1, 3)
```

Table C

```
(1, 1, 3, 0.50)
(2, 4, 5, 0.30)
(3, 6, 9, 0.20)
```

So we then pass in an xml string which we parse and throw into a temp table. The contents of the temp table are that of Table C, without the specific Id.

Then before we save any new records, we need to check if there is an existing Table A record which has both the same number of child records and that those child records match the 3 columns in our temp table (no ID match possible).

Hopefully this is explained well enough, I have done many searches and can't find anything specific to this issue.

Comment: Why use XML when SQL Server 2008 introduced [table valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)?

Comment: Why a "one-to-many relation" with a third table?

Comment: @Oded - cause we have been using Xml since 2000 and we haven't updated code since upgrading to 2008, staying with consistent solution.

Comment: @danihp - Table C has quite a few columns in actual table and by reducing to just two tables, all those columns would have to be repeated in Table B for each corresponding Table A record. Table C are more generic records used for all Table A refrences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a *relational division*.  The article "[Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)" provides a nice summary of various techniques for using SQL to perform a relational division.  For your case, you want the technique listed under "Exact Division":

```
CREATE TABLE tableA (
  Id int PRIMARY KEY,
  Name varchar(25),
  [Desc] varchar(255)
);
INSERT INTO tableA
  (Id, Name, [Desc])
VALUES
  (1, 'Sample 1', 'Should match the XML'),
  (2, 'Sample 2', 'Partial match (should be excluded)'),
  (3, 'Sample 3', 'Has extra matches (should be excluded)');
GO

CREATE TABLE tableB (
  Id int PRIMARY KEY,
  TableAId int,
  TableCId int
);
INSERT INTO tableB
  (Id, TableAId, TableCId)
VALUES
  (1, 1, 1),
  (2, 1, 2),
  (3, 1, 3),
  (4, 2, 1),
  (5, 2, 2),
  (6, 3, 1),
  (7, 3, 2),
  (8, 3, 3),
  (9, 3, 4);
GO

CREATE TABLE tableC (
  Id int PRIMARY KEY,
  StartPosition int,
  EndPosition int,
  Percentage decimal(3,2)
);
INSERT INTO tableC
  (Id, StartPosition, EndPosition, Percentage)
VALUES
  (1, 1, 3, 0.50),
  (2, 4, 5, 0.30),
  (3, 6, 9, 0.20),
  (4, 10, 12, 0.10);
GO

-- this represents the temp table holding the XML data
-- we want to match Sample 1
CREATE TABLE xmlData (
  StartPosition int,
  EndPosition int,
  Percentage decimal(3,2)
);
INSERT INTO xmlData
  (StartPosition, EndPosition, Percentage)
VALUES
  (1, 3, 0.50),
  (4, 5, 0.30),
  (6, 9, 0.20);
GO

SELECT
  b.TableAId
FROM
    tableB AS b
  INNER JOIN
    tableC AS c
  ON
    b.TableCId = c.Id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    xmlData AS x
  ON
    c.StartPosition = x.StartPosition AND
    c.EndPosition = x.EndPosition AND
    c.Percentage = x.Percentage
GROUP BY
  b.TableAId
HAVING
  COUNT(c.Id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xmlData) AND
  COUNT(x.StartPosition) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xmlData);
GO

DROP TABLE xmlData;
DROP TABLE tableC;
DROP TABLE tableB;
DROP TABLE tableA;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a decent solution, I will check it out.

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm, thanks Cheran. Great url reference to boot. Thanks again.